# I was trying to access "UserController@edit" but it doesn't found, what did i do wrong?

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

This is my link

```
<a href="{{ url($i->id.'/edit') }}">edit</a>
```

This is my web.php

```
Route::resource('/', UserController::class);
```

When i run `php artisan route:list` this is the return

> GET|HEAD  | {}/edit  | edit    | App\Http\Controllers\UserController@edit    | web

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be

```php
<a href="{{ route('user.edit', $i->id) }}">edit</a>
```

and

```php
Route::resource('user', UserController::class);
```

The first argument of the resource should be the name of the route group and not the route.

Comment: ahh i see, so i can't use '/' for define the link, thanks

Comment: If you want a custom URI then you simply create a route by hand, it overrides the resource route